# Calling __hash__() method

Tags: python, class, methods

I define class `MyClass()`

```
import random
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __hash__(self):
        return random.randin(1, 10) 
x = MyClass()
```

I know, that `__init__` is called automatically after I declare `x = MyClass()`. But what about `__hash__`? Does it work without being explicitly called by `x.__hash__()` ?
Is every method that starts with `__` called automatically or program decides when to call them?
I went through many documentation to find the answer but unsuccesssfuly.

Thank you for answers!

Comment: Literally the first sentence of https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__ is "Called by built-in function hash() and for operations on members of hashed collections". What's unclear about that?

Answer (score 0):

From Python docs:

> Called by built-in function hash() and for operations on members of hashed collections including set, frozenset, and dict. __hash__() should return an integer. The only required property is that objects which compare equal have the same hash value;

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__

Also, please, don't return random numbers from __hash__().

Comment: "Also, please, don't return random numbers from __hash__()." this is one way to have very funny debugging sessions.

Answer (score 0):

No, `__hash__` is not automatically called. Have a look at [the documentation for this method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> Called by built-in function hash() and for operations on members of
>   hashed collections including set, frozenset, and dict.

So this method will be called in case someone does `hash(x)`.

Btw. returning a random number is a bad idea:

> The only required property is that objects which compare equal have
>   the same hash value